# how to create link edit datatables and ajax.

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I'm still a newbie with datatables and ajax. I want to ask is how to make the edit link on each row of data is displayed in datatables? 
I wrote a query on page pc_list_barcode.php. daftar_barcode.php page to display the query results.

```js
<?php 
include "class/connect_sql.class.php";
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' ) )
{


    
    $query = mssql_query("select TOP 30 barcode_wo_nmr, barcode_wo_line,wo_wks_desc,
   barcode_wo_proses, barcode_npk, barcode_start, barcode_pending, barcode_end,barcode_qty,barcode_ng,barcode_reason_pending
   from WO_ENG_BARCODE, WO_ENG_DET, WO_ENG_DET_WKS  with(nolock) where 
   barcode_wo_nmr= WO_DET_NOMOR and barcode_line = wo_det_line and 
    barcode_wo_nmr = wo_wks_nmr and WO_DET_NOMOR = wo_wks_nmr and barcode_wo_line = wo_wks_line and WO_DET_NAMA_BARANG = wo_wks_barang and right(barcode_wo_nmr,2) = '15'
   order by barcode_wo_nmr asc");
    $jsonResult = '{"data" : [ ';
    $i=0;
    while ($data=mssql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
 {
       if($i != 0)
   {
           $jsonResult .=',';
       }
       $jsonResult .=json_encode($data);
       $i++;
    $data['barcode_wo_nmr'];
   $data['wo_wks_desc'];
   $data['barcode_wo_line'];
   $data['barcode_wo_proses'];
   $data['barcode_npk'];
   $data['barcode_start'];
   $data['barcode_pending'];
   $data['barcode_end'];
   $data['barcode_qty'];
   $data['barcode_ng'];
   $data['barcode_reason_pending'];
    
   }
    $jsonResult .= ']}';
    echo $jsonResult;
} 
else {
    echo '<script>window.location="404.html"</script>';
}
?>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Work Order</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/media/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            
                            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                                <a href="#">Add</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="provinsi">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>No WO</th>
                                            <th>Deskripsi</th>
            <th>Line</th>
                                            <th>Proses</th>
            <th>NPK</th>
                                            <th>Mulai</th>
            <th>Pending</th>
                                            <th>Selesai</th>
            <th>QTY</th>
                                            <th>Not Good</th>
            <th>Reason</th>
             <th>Action</th>
                                          
           
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="asset/script/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="asset/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="asset/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script src="asset/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var t = $('#provinsi').DataTable( {
                    "ajax": "pc_list_barcode.php",
                    "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
                    "columns": [
                        { 
                            "data": "barcode_wo_nmr",
                            "width": "120px",
                            "sClass": "text-center"
                        },
                        { "data": "wo_wks_desc" },
      { "data": "barcode_wo_line" },
      { "data": "barcode_wo_proses" },
      { "data": "barcode_npk" },
      { "data": "barcode_start" },
      { "data": "barcode_pending" },
      { "data": "barcode_end" },
      { "data": "barcode_qty" },
      { "data": "barcode_ng" },
      { "data": "barcode_reason_pending" },
      // {"data": return '<a href="edit_barcode.php?id=' + row.id + '">EDIT</a>' },
                    ]
                } );
            } );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data has 11 fields, your table head has 12 fields and your DataTable initialisation has 9 or 10 fields... If you want to return tweaked html into a row you'll need a render function, from your description it should probably look like this:

```
{
    "data": "unique_id",
    "render": function(data){
        return '<a href="edit_barcode.php?id=' + data + '">EDIT</a>' 
    }
}
```

I couldn't see where the `row.id` you referenced was being set in you PHPs JSON creation so I'm not sure where `unique_id` should be coming from. Basically you'll need to alter this for your use case but if you replace your commented out line with this it should help a little.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry :), one wants to ask. how to add a serial number in each row?

Comment: You mean a unique id? If it's not in your data then you'll need to get it from the server, if it is in your data you'll be able to get it from the click event of the `EDIT` link. It doesn't have to be visible.